# Render in page link

Tags: 8, navigation

How can I render an in page link, like:

```
<a href="#xyz">abc</a>
```

I tried:

```
$options = array('fragment' => 'xyz');
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('abc'), Url::fromUri('internal:/', $options))->toString();
```

...but that gave me: `<a href="http://example.com#xyz">abc</a>`, I want just: `<a href="#xyz">abc</a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the slash from the URI works for me:

```
$link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('abc'), Url::fromUri('internal:', $options))->toString();
```

Produces:

```
<a href="#xyz">abc</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of multiple links in 1 column:

```
$edit_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Edit'), Url::fromUri('internal:/edit/' . $r['id']))->toString();

$remove_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Remove'), Url::fromUri('internal:/remove/' . $r['id']))->toString();

$push_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Push'), Url::fromUri('internal:/push/' . $r['id']))->toString();

$r['id'] = t('@linkEdit | @linkRemove | @linkPush', array('@linkEdit' => $edit_link, '@linkRemove' => $remove_link, '@linkPush' => $push_link));
```